# How to (de-)serialize an object with JAXB/SCALA when an @XmlJavaTypeAdapter is needed?

Tags: scala, annotations, jaxb

I need help using JAXB to (de-)serialize a Polygon of the [JTS Library](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm):

When implementing the

```
class PolygonAdapter extends XmlAdapter[String,Polygon] {...}
```

and annotating the polygon field like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Room")
case class Room(@XmlAttribute name: String, description: String,
                @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(classOf[PolygonAdapter]) polygon: Polygon) {...}
```

I get the part `classOf[PolygonAdapter])` marked reporting the following errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch; found : java.lang.Class[room.PolygonAdapter](classOf[room.PolygonAdapter])     required: java.lang.Class[_ <: 
 javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter]
- annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: classOf[PolygonAdapter]
- annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: classOf{<null>}[PolygonAdapter]{<null>}
- type mismatch; found : java.lang.Class[room.PolygonAdapter](classOf[room.PolygonAdapter])     required: java.lang.Class[_ <: 
 javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter]
- annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: classOf{<null>}[PolygonAdapter]{<null>}
```

### My Questions:

- How can I solve this problem?
- Is there a better way to (de-)serialize a complex object hierarchy in scala than using JAXB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain how to solve your first problem. Might be a problem with annotating a case class? Could try using a non-case class. But again very unsure about that. Might be related to this SO question?

[scala: annotating accessor methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096919/scala-annotating-accessor-methods)

However, have you looked at the Scala's built-in XML features?

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-scalaxml/

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/131

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/working-with-scalas-xml-support

edit: Could be worth to take a look at: http://scalaxb.org/ if you want to avoid using Scala's built in features...